# Populate tr id tag using jstl

Tags: javascript, database, oracle, jstl

I'm trying to retrieve a table from a database and populating it in a table. The table will be editable by using EditableGrid (http://www.editablegrid.net/en). I'm populating the tables automatically like so:

## Report Results

```
<table id="htmlgrid" border="1">

    <!-- column headers -->
    <tr>
        <c:forEach var="columnName" items="${result.columnNames}">
            <th><c:out value="${columnName}" /></th>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>

    <!-- column data -->
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rowsByIndex}">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">
                <td><c:out value="${column}" /></td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

The result is retrieved like so:

```
c = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            ps = c.prepareStatement("select * from test_persons",
                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            Result result = ResultSupport.toResult(rs);

            request.setAttribute("result", result);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request
                    .getRequestDispatcher("/display.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
```

The thing is, in order to use EditableGrid, the tr tags need an id, for example:

```
                    <tr id="R1">
                <td>Duke</td>
                <td>Patience</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>1.842</td>
                <td>uk</td>
                <td>patience.duke@gmail.com</td>
                <td>false</td>
                <td>11/12/2002</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="R2">
                <td>Rogers</td>
                <td>Denise</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>1.627</td>
                <td>us</td>
                <td>rogers.d@gmail.com</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>07/05/2003</td>
            </tr>
```

How would I use the jstl to automatically put in the  tags in? The database may return any number of rows depending on the query. Is this possible? Or is there a better solution to populate a table from a resultset and make it editable (for the purposes of updating the database later on).

Answer (score 0):

Well... inside your loop over the rows, you would write:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rowsByIndex}">
    <tr id="${row.id}">
```

Comment: hey, I get the following error 

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)

Comment: Also, EditableGrid seems to want to use tags like <tr id="R1">  <tr id="R2">  <tr id="R3">  etc